# Inserting a multi-paged PDF document in a LyX document.

Tags: lyx, pdfpages

I can successfully insert a PDF document in a LyX document using *Insert -> File -> External Material* (choosing *PDFPages* in the template dropdown). The PDF document shows up in the LyX document, however, when I click export the LyX document to a PDF document, the inserted file doesn't appear.

Where can the problem be?

Comment: seems like it only works if you view in pdflatex and not post script or other forms..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about your method (hadn't noticed that option, will have to check that out) but what worked for me was to create a new file for each page of the pdf and insert it as an image inside a float

Answer (score 6):

to insert all pages of your PDF document add

pages=-

to the LaTeX and LyX Options tab when inserting the external file as suggested above. For specific pages follow the instructions as also given in the Template dialog box of the PDFpages template in the 'File' tab of the LyX: External Material window